# Installation of OpenGL under Cygwin

Tags: opengl, cygwin

I want to install the OpenGL library under CygWin.
I added the Cygwin packages: `tiff-opengl`,`libQtOpenGL4`,`libQtOpenGl4-devel`. Probably I don't need the last 2 packeges- I installed them to try to run the OpenGL.
The program that I want to comile using OpenGL, named `test15.c` is:

```
 #include <GL/gl.h>
 #include <GL/glut.h>
 void display()
{
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
      glutInit(&argc, argv);
      glutDisplayFunc(display);
      glutMainLoop();
}
```

However, I've got all these error messages.

```
User@User-PC ~/toto
$ gcc -o test15.exe test15.c -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lglut32
In file included from /usr/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:129:0,
                 from /usr/include/GL/glut.h:17,
                 from test15.c:2:
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:68:79: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 void APIENTRY gluQuadricCallback(GLUquadric *qobj,GLenum which,void (CALLBACK *fn)());
                                                                               ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:78:79: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 void APIENTRY gluTessCallback(GLUtesselator *tess,GLenum which,void (CALLBACK *fn)());
                                                                               ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:94:75: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 void APIENTRY gluNurbsCallback(GLUnurbs *nobj,GLenum which,void (CALLBACK *fn)());
                                                                           ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:96:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUquadricErrorProc)(GLenum);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:97:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessBeginProc)(GLenum);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:98:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessEdgeFlagProc) (GLboolean);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:99:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessVertexProc)(void *);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:100:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessEndProc)(void);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:101:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessErrorProc)(GLenum);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:102:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessCombineProc)(GLdouble[3],void*[4],GLfloat[4],void**);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:103:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessBeginDataProc)(GLenum,void *);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:104:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessEdgeFlagDataProc) (GLboolean,void *);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:105:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessVertexDataProc)(void *,void *);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:106:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessEndDataProc)(void *);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:107:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessErrorDataProc)(GLenum,void *);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:108:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessCombineDataProc)(GLdouble[3],void*[4],GLfloat[4],void**,void*);
                        ^
/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:109:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUnurbsErrorProc)(GLenum);
                        ^
```

What can I do to be able to compile the code using `OpenGL`?

Comment: The OpenGL support in Cygwin is not up to current day standards. OpenGL is not a library, but a layer (Open Graphics Layer) that's being used to talk to the graphics driver. The OpenGL interface implementation in Cygwin talks to X11 servers; which on *nix systems are where the graphics driver lives. In Cygwin the X11 server is a wrapper on top of the Windows GDI and for compatibility and portability reasons only passes through a limited OpenGL profile. You should always use native OpenGL.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by native OpenGL?  What is non-native OpenGL?

Comment: Non native is that `libGL` that's part of Cygwin to provide compatibility for programs that have been written to exclusively use GLX/X11 to create a render context and window. In this configuration all OpenGL commands (and contexts) are of the *indirect* kind, by which all OpenGL commands are first sent (as RPC) to the Cygwin X11 server which proxies them to the Windows WGL/GDI counterparts. The problem with this is, that this works only for OpenGL commands for which there are GLX opcodes; also using extensions is hardly possible (except for the really common ones).

Comment: Native is talking directly to the WGL parts of Windows using the `opengl32` interface. Doesn't work though X11. Definitely can be done with Cygwin, but all of the prebuilt libraries are built to use the GLX/X11 interface, which is emulated. – If you want an open and *nix like working environment in Windows that targets the native APIs use MSys2/MinGW. Also has a much nicer package manager IMHO (pacman of ArchLinux). Get the installer here https://msys2.github.io/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I use OpenGL in the MSys2 environment, will the code using OpenGL comile also in on a Linux machine?

Comment: If you stick to using cross plattform framework and wrapper libraries, like GLUT, GLFW, SDL or Qt, then yes. There are, of course, a lot of plattform dependent details in creating a OpenGL context. However using those native APIs is cumbersome and hardly anybody uses them directly and uses the next available framework that matches the requirements. Your program is using GLUT, so that base has been covered for you. Only one little addition: If compiling for Windows you must include the `windows.h` header before anything related to OpenGL. As simple as `#ifdef _WIN32 #include <windows.h> #endif`